# Can SQL IN() operators be stacked in a more efficient way?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following code that will sum the page views of the first two sessions for visitors who:

1. have made an order anytime, AND
2. has logged `session_index=1`, AND
3. has logged `session_index=2`

within the sampled dataset.

```
SELECT SUM(a.page_views)
FROM sessions a
WHERE a.id IN (
    SELECT b.id 
    FROM sessions b 
    WHERE b.order_id NOTNULL
        /*lookup for visitors who have made a purchase*/
)
AND a.id IN (
    SELECT c.id 
    FROM sessions c 
    WHERE c.session_index = 1
        /*lookup for visitors who have logged session_index #1*/
)
AND a.id IN (
    SELECT d.id
    FROM sessions d
    WHERE d.session_index = 2
        /*lookup for visitors who have logged session_index #2*/
)
AND a.session_index < 3;
    /*makes the SELECT SUM() add records with index #1 and #2.
```

It has pretty terrible efficiency because it does a lookup comparison three times separately. Is there a more efficient way to create a lookup table that combines the three criteria for the lookup table into one?

Comment: Have you tried using an `OR`  condition in these inner queries?

Comment: would that by a single `IN()` where the criteria are `OR`'s? I have not. I will now and see if the result matches the above

Comment: If not, it could help to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @NicoHaase attempting to combine into one `IN()` with `OR` separating the criteria produces a widly different sum. I don't think that is the solution. I'll look through your link you provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the ids that satisfy your conditions with this query:

```
SELECT id
FROM sessions
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(order_id) AND SUM(session_index = 1) AND SUM(session_index = 2)
```

You can use it with the operator `IN` to sum the page views:

```
SELECT SUM(page_views)
FROM sessions
WHERE session_index < 3
AND id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM sessions
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(order_id) AND SUM(session_index = 1) AND SUM(session_index = 2)
)
```

Or you can do it with the window function `SUM()`:

```
SELECT SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN session_index IN (1, 2) THEN page_views END)) OVER ()
FROM sessions
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(order_id) AND SUM(session_index = 1) AND SUM(session_index = 2)
```

Comment: The numbers received from your suggestions exactly match my less efficient methods. Thank you for providing this, `HAVING` was the missing puzzle piece I think I was looking for.

Comment: If your version of SQLite supports window functions, my last query should be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(page_views)
FROM (SELECT s.id, SUM(s.page_views) as page_views
      FROM sessions s
      WHERE s.session_index < 3
      GROUP BY s.id
      HAVING CCOUNT(s.order_id) > 0 AND  -- users have made a purchase
             SUM(CASE WHEN s.session_index = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
             SUM(CASE WHEN s.session_index = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
    ) s;
```

That said, your original version with the right indexes and using `EXISTS` might be the fastest method:

```
SELECT SUM(s.page_views)
FROM sessions s
WHERE a.session_index < 3 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM sessions s2 
              WHERE s2.id = s.id AND s2.order_id NOT NULL
             ) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM sessions s2 
              WHERE s2.id = s.id AND s2.session_index = 1
             ) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM sessions s2 
              WHERE s2.id = s.id AND s2.session_index = 2
             ) ;
```

And the index you want is on `sessions(id, session_index, order_id)`.